# How to convert SearchResponse to JsValue

Tags: scala, play-json, elastic4s

I wonder if there is some straight way to convert `com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchResponse` to  `play.api.libs.json.JsValue`.

I see the `SearchHit` in `SearchResponse` can be transformed to JSON String via method `sourceAsString`.

but I need some info in `SearchResponse` such as total hits.

Answer (score 0):

```
x is Response[SearchResponse]

val s = x.result.hits.hits.map(x => x.sourceAsString)

// hit count
val totalCount = x.result.hits.total
```